# Show that $|\frac{(1-\alpha)(1+(e^{jw})^{-1})}{2(1-\alpha (e^{jw})^{-1})}|^2 = \frac{(1-\alpha)^2(1+\cos(w))}{2(1+\alpha^2-2\alpha \cos(w)}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given
$$ 
H_{LP}(z) = \frac{1-\alpha}{2}\frac{1+z^{-1}}{1-\alpha z^{-1}}
$$
Show that 
$$
|H_{LP}(e^{j\omega})|^{2} = \frac{(1-\alpha)^2(1+\cos(\omega))}{2(1+\alpha^2-2\alpha \cos(\omega)}
$$

So far, I  have taken $|H_{LP}(e^{j\omega})| = \frac{1-\alpha}{2}\frac{1+\cos(\omega)}{1-\alpha \cos(\omega)}$

Squaring it subsequently gives $\frac{(1-\alpha)^{2}}{4}\frac{(1+\cos(\omega))^{2}}{1-2\alpha \cos(\omega) + \alpha ^{2}\cos^{2} (\omega)}$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here...

Comment: Is $\alpha$ real?

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ is real

Comment: How did you obtain $|H_{LP}(e^{i\omega})| = \frac{1-\alpha}{2}\frac{1+\cos(\omega)}{1-\alpha \cos(\omega)}$?

Comment: Hmm, now that you've pointed it out that seems wrong. I was taking the absolute value to be the real part of $e^{iw}$. If I were to take $|e^{jw}|$ as 1 then wouldn't the entire expression cancel to 1?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $|z|^2=z\overline z$. To warm up, consider $|1+z^{-1}|^2$
where $z=e^{it}$ with $t$ real. Then
$$|1+z^{-1}|^2=|1+e^{-it}|^2=(1+e^{-it})\overline{(1+e^{-it})}
=(1+e^{-it})(1+e^{it})
=2+e^{it}+e^{-it}$$
etc.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that this is called the absolute square/squared norm.